# Why is VBA autofilter does not filter by greater than date?

Tags: excel, vba, date, autofilter

I've been working on the feature for the bookings sheet my team is using at work - to create a summary of the bookings by the supplier. I have done most of the work, the `UserForm` and `InputBox` works perfect however once I am adding the `autofilter` into the range of table object it only filters by the exact match like `Criteria1:="01/04/2021"`. When trying to use `greater than` it does not apply filter at all. I've done some digging and found out that this might be due dates being actually in string format rather than raw dates, not really sure how I could tackle this.

I have tried to go around and add autofilter into the ready summary that is created from a template but, every time it throws me weird errors like `object variable or with block not set` or `for loop not initialised` in the code that has been working a second ago - only added line is just before the end of the `CreateSummary` sub:

```
Template.Sheets(1).ListObjects(1).Range.AutoFilter Filed:=3, Criteria1:=">01/04/2021"
```

Below whole code:

```
Sub CreateSummary()

    ' start new debugging log
    Debug.Print (vbCrLf & TimeStamp() & ": " & "--- Start" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf)

    ' declare vars
    Dim SearchTerm As String
    Dim SearchDate As Date
    
    Dim Template As Workbook
    Dim Tracker As Workbook
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Found As Integer
    Dim Today As Date
    Today = Date
    
    Dim CurrentRowCount As Long
    Dim LastRowCount As Long
    Dim FirstEmpty As Long
    
    ' set defaults
    Set Tracker = Application.ThisWorkbook
    SearchDate = Date
    Summary.ClickedAll = Null
    i = 1
    Found = 0
    LastRowCount = 0
    
    ' handle user input
    SearchTerm = InputBox("Please type name of the supplier (it can be just a partial e.g. 'moln' for Molnlycke")
    If SearchTerm = vbNullString Then
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf Len(SearchTerm) < 2 Then
        MsgBox ("The search term have to be minimum 2 characters." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Please run macro again.")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    SummaryOptions.Show

    
    ' Open template file and clear its contents
    Set Template = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\RJamborski\Desktop\Summary Template.xlsx")
    Set TemplateTable = Template.Sheets(1).ListObjects(1)
        TemplateTable.DataBodyRange.ClearContents
    
    ' loop over all worksheets to find all booking sheets
    For Each WS In Tracker.Worksheets
        If WS.Visible And Not WS.Name = "Matrix" Then ' if worksheet is not visible and not a Matrix
            If InStr(1, WS.Name, "Template", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then ' if worksheet is not a template
                Debug.Print (vbCrLf & TimeStamp() & ": " & "-- Iteration #" & i)
                WS.Activate
                Set WSTable = WS.ListObjects(1)
                ' check if filter is on and clear it
                Call ClearFilters(WS)
                
                ' apply filters
                ' filter by search term in 'supplier' column
                WSTable.Range.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="=*" & SearchTerm & "*", Operator:=xlAnd
                ' if option 'All Bookings' has been clicked apply more criteria (filter out cancelled & past bookings)
                If Summary.ClickedAll = False Then
                    With WSTable.Range
                        .AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="=*" & SearchTerm & "*"
                        .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=ECOM", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=Planned"
                        
                        ' NEED FIX: on working with string dates
                        .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=">" & CDate(4 / 4 / 2021), Operator:=xlAnd
                    End With
                End If

                ' check if DataBodyRange (table's content object) has any height / content found
                On Error GoTo NoCellsFound
                If WSTable.DataBodyRange.Height > 0 Then
                    Debug.Print (TimeStamp() & ": " & "Data found in " & WS.Name)
                    
                   
                    ' set first empty cell reference
                    If Found = 0 Then
                        FirstEmpty = 2
                    ElseIf Found > 0 Then
                        ' fix when there is only one record in template
                        If LastRowCount > 10000 Then
                            FirstEmpty = 2
                        Else
                            FirstEmpty = LastRowCount + 1
                        End If
                    End If
                    Debug.Print (TimeStamp() & ": " & "First Empty = " & FirstEmpty)
                   
                    Found = Found + 1
                   
                    ' select and copy all visble/filtered data
                    WSTable.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
                    Selection.Copy
                    Template.Sheets(1).Activate
                    Template.Sheets(1).Range("A" & FirstEmpty).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                        Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                                        

                    ' fill in S column with WS.Name value & weekday text value formula in column A
                    CurrentRowCount = GetTotalRows(Template.Sheets(1))
                    Debug.Print (TimeStamp() & ": " & "Current Row Count = " & CurrentRowCount)
                    
                    Debug.Print (TimeStamp() & ": " & "Last Row Count = " & LastRowCount)
                    Debug.Print (TimeStamp() & ": " & "Loop rows " & FirstEmpty & " to " & CurrentRowCount)
                    For n = FirstEmpty To CurrentRowCount
                        Template.Sheets(1).Range("S" & n).Value = WS.Name
                        Template.Sheets(1).Range("A" & n).Formula = "=TEXT(C" & n & ", ""dddd"")"
                    Next n
                       
                    ' update last row count after filling required cells
                    LastRowCount = GetTotalRows(Template.Sheets(1))
                    
                End If ' if DataBodyRange.height > 0

NoCellsFound: ' if no data found in filtered view

                ' update iterator
                i = i + 1
                ' clear filters
                Call ClearFilters(WS)
                
            End If
        End If
    Next WS
    
    ' once complete show top of the template file to the user / reset defaults
    Template.Activate
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
    Range("G2").Select
    
    ' for some reason this line breaks the whole loop / WS loop reference looses pointer?
    Template.Sheets(1).ListObjects(1).Range.AutoFilter Filed:=3, Criteria1:=">01/04/2021"
    
    Debug.Print (TimeStamp() & ": " & "End Sub: Found " & LastRowCount - 1 & " records in " & Found & " sites.")
End Sub

Function GetTotalRows(Worksheet)
    Set DBR = Worksheet.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange
    
    If DBR.Cells(1, "B").End(xlDown).Row > 10000 Then
        GetTotalRows = 2
    Else
        GetTotalRows = DBR.Cells(1, "B").End(xlDown).Row
    End If
End Function

Function ClearFilters(ByRef Worksheet As Worksheet)
    
    Worksheet.Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    
    On Error Resume Next
    If (ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode And ActiveSheet.FilterMode) Then
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    End If
    
    On Error Resume Next
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    End If
    
    On Error Resume Next
    If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    End If
End Function
```

There is a lot of `Debug.Print` calls here as I have been trying to understand what is exactly going on at every step the macro is running.

If someone would have any idea how I can tackle this I would be really grateful. I've been trying to get over this for few days now with no luck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

VBA uses octothorpes for date values, so:

```
Template.Sheets(1).ListObjects(1).Range.AutoFilter Filed:=3, Criteria1:=">#01/04/2021#"
```

Comment: `Range.AutoFilter` doesn't use `#` though with date criteria, as can be easily verified with the macro recorder.

Comment: @BigBen: Missed the closing double-quote. Is that it?

Comment: No. I used the macro recorder and got `">01/04/2021"`, without `#`. While your first sentence is correct, this is the Excel Object Model, which for `Range.AutoFilter` doesn't use `#`.

Comment: @BigBen: OK. Then the questioneer's original code should work.

Comment: I've tried both. However, I just run this for the first time at home and, it worked! Using the non-hashed way to handle dates. I can only assume this could be a problem with 32/64-bit versions of Excel as this is the only enviormental difference I can think of. I have 64-bit Excel and workstations at work has 32-bit. Could this be an issue? If so is there a way to go around it?

Comment: More likely, it’s the regional settings of Windows.